# How can I use wiki markup in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wiki

I've been using wordpress and really don't like the wysiwyg editor. I really don't want to spend a lot of time with the HTML too. What I would like is to be able to use Wiki Markup for my post. Searching for wiki markup plugins on wordpress isn't very helpful. The one plugin that looked interesting was WP-MediaWiki, but this plugin doesn't play very well with other plugins. I would really like to have  Atlassian Confluence like wiki syntax.

Comment: did WP MarkItUp work for you?

Comment: Not completely. The Admin doesn't work so I can't switch to Wiki Markup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try [WP MarkItUp](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-markitup/), it even provides creating custom markup:

> *"WP MarkItUp! is the WordPress plugin that replaces the old "quicktags"
>   toolbar with MarkItUp!, a lightweight
>   jQuery plugin that allows to turn any
>   textarea into an highly customizable
>   markup editor. XHTML, Textile, Wiki,
>   Markdown and BBcode toolbars are
>   already provided out-of-the-box, but
>   even your own markup syntax can be
>   easily implemented with this system.
>   The plugin currently features three
>   different skins for the toolbar, new
>   ones are about to come."*

Comment: "Last Updated: 2009-8-25" :(